# How does Laravel Validate String?

Tags: laravel, validation

When I use Laravel's string validation rule, what exactly is it doing?  For example, does it simply run php's `is_string()` method, or does it run `filter_var()` perhaps, with the `FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP` constant?

Secondly, how do I strip tags using Laravel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use Laravel's string validation, the following function gets called

```
protected function validateAttribute($attribute, $rule) { ... }
```

which you could find in

> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php

and if you examine the method, you'll find this piece of code

```
$method = "validate{$rule}";

if ($validatable && ! $this->$method($attribute, $value, $parameters, $this)) {
    $this->addFailure($attribute, $rule, $parameters);
}
```

which would call the trait `Concerns\ValidatesAttributes`

```
/**
 * Validate that an attribute is a string.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @return bool
 */
public function validateString($attribute, $value)
{
    return is_string($value);
}
```

and to strip tags you could use PHP's [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) method

Answer (score 3):

> When I use Laravel's string validation rule, what exactly is it doing?

When you use Laravel's string validation rule, it only checks if **the field under validation is of string type or not**.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#rule-string

> how do I strip tags using Laravel?

You can use the **strip_tags()** function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this

This are some validations i used in my  current project,it is based on user input.

```
$username = $request->get('username');
$email = $request->get('email');
$password = $request->get('password');
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
      return abort(403, 'Username should be alphanumeric');
   }
if(strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 25){
      return abort(403, 'Username should mbe minimum 3 and max 25 characters');
   }
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      return abort(403, 'Invalid Email Format,eg abc@xyz.com');
   }
if(strlen($password) < 6){
      return abort(403, 'Password should be minimum six characters');
   }
```

refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation.

To strip tags in laravel you can use **`strip_tags()`** function in your code .The strip_tags() function strips a string from HTML, XML, and PHP tags. HTML comments are always stripped. This cannot be changed with the allow parameter. This function is binary-safe.